# Wildcard certificate with SAN

Tags: windows, iis, ssl, certificate, encryption

I am attempting to create a wildcard SSL cert with a Subject Alternative Name (SAN) for use in IIS 7.5 and I'm having some issues. Because I need to include a SAN, I am using the Custom Certificate Request tool under the Certificates snap-in on Windows.

Thus far, I have managed to get a working wildcard certificate when I use the IIS 7.5 Create Certificate Request wizard, and a working SAN certificate when I use the Custom Certificate Request wizard (in the Certificates snap-in), but I have been unable to get both working in the same cert.

The cert which I generated with the Custom Certificate Request wizard has the following properties:

> Subject Name:
>
> - CN=*.domain.local
>
> Alternative Name:
>
> - DNS=domain.local
>
> Extended Key Usage:
>
> - Server Authentication
>
> (Private) Key Type:
>
> - Exchange
>
> (Private) Key Options:
>
> - Key size: 2048
> - [x] Make private key exportable

With the above cert in IIS 7.5, requests to the SAN of https://domain.local are secure, but https://*.domain.local requests are unsecure with the browser stating that the cert is only valid for domain.local (instead of *.domain.local).

Ultimately, my objective is to have a cert which works on *.domain.local *and* domain.local.

Using the Custom Certificate Request wizard in the Windows Certificates snap-in, how can I create a certificate request for a cert containing a wildcard and a SAN attribute?

Comment: What do the subject and subject alternate name attributes on the certificate look like?

Comment: @ShaneMadden They are exactly as defined in the request.

Comment: This is exactly how it is supposed to work. Perhaps you should post your request and certificate files in PEM format for further examination

Comment: @syneticon-dj Do you happen to know how i can export my request as PEM? The only option I'm given with the request wizard is Base64 or Binary output.

Comment: PEM is Base64 encoded as well, but you are right, you do not get it as an export choice. I was just aiming at the fact that it should be ASCII-only so it could be published easily, so feel free to export in any Base64-encoded format and pasting into your question. Make sure **not** to export the private key :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a subject alternative name is in place, the common name (edit: from the subject) is no longer used. Solution: Add the wildcard name to the list of subject alternative names.